# How to drop whole response if i got wrong data from request Scrapy?

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I scraped page that contain: name, url1, url2  =  25 Items.
In Url2 i have string that contain something like that :
"q=Dummy&bla=**h**" or "q=Dummy&bla=**g**" or "q=Dummy&bla=**j**"

So i need to check if there "q=Dummy&bla=**h**"  we continue, else we drop name,url,and url2

that have "q=Dummy&bla=**g**", "q=Dummy&bla=**j**" and go to next name, url, url2.

Where should i create if else statement , so i can drop not only **url2** but **name**,and **url1**.

In result we have: 21names, 21 url1 and 21 url2 that contain only "q=Dummy&bla=**h**".

I`m for sure that i must write some code on middlewares.py, but dont know where.

Please without code just need little hint, maybe on DownloaderMiddleware class i dont know.
**Example**

```py
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/page=1"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for selects in response.css('div.scrapdata'):
            il = ItemLoader(item=ExampleItem(), selector=selects, response=response)
            
                il.add_css('name', 'div.name')
                il.add_css('img_link', 'img::attr(src)')
                il.add_css('page_name', 'a::attr(href)')
                yield il.load_item()
```

Need check this:

```py
if "q=Dummy&bla=h" in il.add_css('page_name', 'a::attr(href)'):
    WE parse name, img_link, page_name
else:
    We go to next name, img_link, page_name
```

Data in json:

```json
{
"name":["Alex"], "img_link":"example.com/pics/Alex.jpg", 
 "page_name":"example.com/q=Dummy&bla=h/Alex.html"
}
```

Comment: Your question/issue isn't clear.  Please provide more details and create a [mre]. Please also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you scrapped 5 urls like this:

```
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=h/Alex.html"
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=g/Bart.html"
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=h/Chris.html"
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=j/Diego.html"
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=h/Evan.html"
```

And want remove urls that contain bla=j or bla=g:

```
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=j/Diego.html
example.com/q=Dummy&bla=g/Bart.html
```

You need edit pipelines, check docs pipelines for example
Thanks for answers